# Is it possible to create a separate 404 page for a WordPress site within a WordPress site? Any suggestions on how to do this?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

Iam a newbie at wordpress and I have a WordPress site that is contained inside a sub-folder of another WordPress site. I am wondering if it is possible if I can create a separate 404 page for the site that is contained in the sub-folder. I tried to create a 404 page but when I tried to test it, the 404 page of the root site appears. Any suggestions on how to make this work? Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you tried replacing the default Wordpress 404 page? There is an existing 404 page on Wordpress, try backing that up and replacing it with your PHP page to see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Put a .htaccess file in the subfolder and have it contain:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

Where /404.html is the path to the correct 404 page.